# Batch file to replace string after other string?

Tags: batch-file

I have these 2 files:

test.txt
test1.txt

This is the content of the first file:

```
build.date=220314
build.version=1.0Rel
build.id=TestBuild1.0
build.type=DEV
```

This is the content of the second one:

```
build.date=220314
build.version=1.3
build.id=TestBuildRedDot
build.type=DEV
```

Now. What I want is a batch file that changes the text that comes after "build.id=" (supposing that I don't know what comes after it). Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the lines in the file, then you can use FINDSTR to strip out the old build.id line and write the result to a new file. Then append a new line with the new value. Finally move the new file to the original name.

```
@echo off
>file.txt.new (
  findstr /vbl "build.id=" file.txt
  echo build.id=NewValue
)
move /y file.txt.new file.txt >nul
```

If you want to preserve the line order, then use FOR /F to read each line, parsing the line into variable name and value. Then a simple IF statement can be used to process the line accordingly.

```
@echo off
>file.txt.new (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (file.txt) do (
    if "%%A" == "build.id" (
      echo build.id=NewValue
    ) else (
      echo %%A=%%B
    )
  )
)
move /y file.txt.new file.txt >nul
```

Or you can make the task really simple by getting your hands on a utility that supports regular expression search and replace. I have written a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that I find extremely useful. Here is how it could be used for your simple task.

```
@echo off
type file.txt | repl "^(build\.id=).*" "($1)NewVaue" >file.txt.new
move /y file.txt.new file.txt >nul
```

Comment: Btw, how to do this on a bash (Linux) script?

Comment: @user3479320 - That is an entirely different question that I'm sure has been asked and answered many times. Check out the awk and sed utilities.